# AWS IoT Core topic wildcard: what was the value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, wildcard, iot

We are setting up AWS IoT core to stream data to a TimeStream database.
Different equipment will post to different topics.
E.g. serial number 1234 => topic equipment/1234/counters/starttime
That makes it pretty easy to handle the security.
When creating a rule, the subscription uses wildcards and becomes something like this:
SELECT timestamp FROM 'equipment/+/counters/#'

The question: how can we in the action use the values of the wildcards?
In the example, the + wildcard would have value '1234'
It seems a bit silly and certainly less secure to have the same number also included in the payload.

In the action to put the values in the timestream database it seems you can only use fields in the payload. Or is there some way to get the original topic? That would of course also help (albeit less elegant than gettnig the value of the wildcards).

Comment: Hi,
I would suggest to not use direct integration between iot rule and TimeStream. The reason is because, there is no batching happening and it is not very flexible. I'd suggest to put a kinesis data stream (or SQS) and lambda to write data in batch into Timestream. You gain in flexibility and cost at scale.

Comment: I mean Kinesis + lambda between iot rule and TimeStream.

Answer (score 0):

There seems not to be a thing like wildcard naming.
But there is the function topic().
In the above example topic(2) would be the 2nd part of the topic, so corresponds to the '+' in the topic subscription.
This works in the SELECT.
This also works in the definition of a Dimension. In the above example, a dimension could be defined as ${topic(2)}